# Atheros driver was there and now its gone!

Tags: networking

I just installed Ubuntu on my hard drive.

I am not connected to the internet because Ubuntu does not recognize my Atheros AR8161 ethernet.

Therefore I have downloaded a total of 11 files in order to make build-essential and linux headers.

I then use this package to make the driver module:

compat-wireless-3.5.4-1-snpc

Right after I installed Ubuntu, I ran all this and it worked. Ubuntu recognized my driver.

But then when I rebooted everything was gone!

Firstly, I don't want to have to go through all this every time I boot Ubuntu.

Secondly, I did exactly what I did the first time, but now the second time I get error messages.

Here is the output:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/1369897/

You can see from the output that build essential and linux headers are ready to go....I think....maybe I didnt wait long enough?

Answer (score 0):

I see where you installed linux-image-3.2.0-**34** but linux-headers--3.2.0-**33**. Please check and correct, if necessary, that you have headers matching your running kernel:

```
    sudo dpkg -s linux-headers-`uname-r`
```

Those backticks are on the left side of my US keyboard on the same key with ~.

Then I'd try again including additional steps:

```
    ./scripts/driver-select restore
    make clean
    ./scripts/driver-select alx
    make
    sudo make install
    sudo modprobe alx
```

You will need to recompile for a newer running kernel whenever Update Manager installs one using the steps just above.

Comment: OK I am going to change to linux-image-3.2.0-33, but I was running -34 before and it worked.

Comment: Are linux-headers-3.2.0-34 not available?

Comment: Well, I have 3 dependencies on linux-headers--3.2.0-33, so it just seemed easiest to change the image to 33. Let me run 33 and see what happens. I don't know how this mix up happened in the first place, but you can see that running after all these dependencies can lead to confusion.

Comment: OK, that wasn't a good idea to go ahead with the  linux-headers--3.2.0-33 so I went with the  linux-headers--3.2.0-34. This produced some errors, but lo and behold the Ethernet was working! I rebooted twice, and it was working both times. So that is progress. I still have problems connecting to internet, which I will post in a separate thread.